# Twilio Studio to have a phone number as an intermediary?

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I've created a Twilio flow that would forward new messages or calls to my phone number. What I'd like to do is if I reply to the forwarded text from Twilio that it would send my reply to the last text message sender that's not my number. How could I do that with Studio, I am at a loss here? Is it even possible with Twilio Studio?

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

For two-way SMS forwarding, I would use Twilio Functions instead of Twilio Studio--to do that, [check out this blog post by my teammate Tilde](https://www.twilio.com/blog/forwarding-sms-phone-calls-alternate-number).